# How to set up Yarn on OpenServer?

Tags: windows, hadoop-yarn

My problem described in the title.

But in addition, I have set in the next directiory **C:\OpenServer\modules\yarn** Yarn and I don't know what to do next.

I hope for your help because I didn't find anything on Google or in the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Yeh!

We need to change in settings on the 'server' tab one option and create a file that will say which programs OpenServer must get and prefetch.